# conditioning in XML parsing - PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Its been a while since the last time I was coding, and I am a little rusty. I am trying to parse an xml file and having a problem with the condition. Spent hours trying to figure out where is the problem, but without success...

**PHP CODE:**

```
<div id="gallery">
    <?php 
    $cat_img="images/cat.png";
    $logo_path="logos/";

    $file = simplexml_load_file('stores.xml');
    $old_cat="";

    foreach($file->store as $store){
        if($store->cat != $old_cat){
            echo "<img id='cat' src='".$cat_img."'><div id='cat_text'>".$store->cat."</div><br>";
            $old_cat=$store->cat;
        }

        echo "<div id='store'><img id='store_img' src='".$logo_path.$store->logo."' alt='logo'><br>";
        echo "<store_name>".$store->name."</store_name>";
        echo "<phone>".$store->phone."</phone><phone>טל:&nbsp;</phone></div>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

STORES.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<stores>

    <store><logo>renuar.jpg</logo>
    <name>renuar</name>
    <phone>052-6059962</phone>
    <cat>clothing</cat></store>

    <store><logo>yoop.jpg</logo>
    <name>YOOP</name>
    <phone>08-6601451</phone>
    <cat>clothing</cat></store>

....

</stores>
```

The idea is to print every store, when category changes it should print the category divider and keep printing the stores. Somehow the condition is always true and I have no idea why...

p.s
If anyone has a better idea on how to divide the categories, a different method, I would be happy to hear.

Thanks!!!

Comment: put $old_cat=$store->cat; after the if - not in the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$store->cat` will be `SimpleXMLElement` `object` and two object will not be same even with same category name. You need to `cast` it to `string` for comparison

Like `(string) $store->cat`, try this:

```
<?php
$cat_img = "images/cat.png";
$logo_path = "logos/";
$file = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$old_cat = "";
foreach ($file->store as $store) {
    if ((string) $store->cat != $old_cat) {
        echo "<img id='cat' src='" . $cat_img . "'><div id='cat_text'>category: " . $store->cat . "</div><br>";
        $old_cat = (string) $store->cat;
    }
    echo "<div id='store'><img id='store_img' src='" . $logo_path . $store->logo . "' alt='logo'><br>";
    echo "<store_name>" . $store->name . "</store_name>";
    echo "<phone>" . $store->phone . "</phone><phone>טל:&nbsp;</phone></div>";
}
?>
```